# Input box wrong positioning in menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to add an input box to the most right side of the bar on the same line as those menu bars, but everytime its positioned bad or its not even there. Can you help me with this? It needs to be in the menu bar because of my JS hide-on-scroll function. I'm trying to use JQuery-ui's

```
DatePicker ("$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker();
});")
```

HTML:

```
  <nav>
<span class="nadpis"><a href="javascript:history.go(0)" style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $id_dom; ?></a></span>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p></span>
<ul class="nav">
  <li class="prve">
    <a href="#">PSI</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="flvmena/meno1.html">Simoncik</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flvmena/meno2.html">Kodrla</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flvmena/meno3.html">Vajs</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flvmena/meno4.html">Hrebicek</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flcmena/meno1.html">Bednarikova</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flcmena/meno2.html">Dobrikova</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flcmena/meno3.html">Duracka</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="quamena/meno1.html">Klco</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="quamena/meno2.html">Cisar</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li><!--
  --><li class="druhe">
    <a href="#">&#9776;</a>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="index.php">RPO</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flv.php?id_dom=flv">FLV</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="flvmena/meno1.html">Simoncik</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flvmena/meno2.html">Kodrla</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flvmena/meno3.html">Vajs</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flvmena/meno4.html">Hrebicek</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flv.php?id_dom=FLC">FLC</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="flcmena/meno1.html">Bednarikova</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flcmena/meno2.html">Dobrikova</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flcmena/meno3.html">Duracka</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flv.php?id_dom=QUA">QUA</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="quamena/meno1.html">Klco</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="quamena/meno2.html">Cisar</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flv.php?id_dom=HFX">HFX</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flv.php?id_dom=PDT">PDT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flv.php?id_dom=RSH">RSH</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flv.php?id_dom=BUR">BUR</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="suhrn.php?id_dom=SUHRN" style="color: #ea9b54">SUHRN</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="suhrn.php?id_dom=INCI" style="color: #ea9b54">INCI</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="suhrn.php?id_dom=JIRA" style="color: #ea9b54">JIRA</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="suhrn.php?id_dom=CHGT" style="color: #ea9b54">CHGT</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="flv.php?id_dom=TASK" style="color: #ea9b54">TASK</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="vrs.php" style="color: #ea9b54">VRS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
nav {
display: inline-block;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #303036;
vertical-align: top;
top: -1px;
opacity: 1;
transition: .3s;
}

nav:hover {
opacity: 1 !important;
transition: .3s;
}
/*Nadpis - nazov domainu/reportu */
span.nadpis a{
left: 0;
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
color: #FAFAC1;
background-color: #303036;
font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: 700;
}

.nav a {
display: block;
background-color: #303036;
color: #fff;
text-decoration: none;
padding: .7em 1.7em;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-size: 85%;
letter-spacing: 3px;
position: relative;
}

.nav {
vertical-align: top;
display: inline-block;
width: 250px;
}

.nav li {
position: relative;
}

.nav > li {
display: inline-block;
}

.nav li:hover > a {
transition: .3s;
background-color: #2e86ab;
color: #8fc93a;
}

.nav ul {
 position: absolute;
white-space: nowrap;
z-index: 1;
left: -99999em;
border: 2px solid #81D4FA;
border-top: 1px solid #81D4FA;
}

.nav > li:hover > ul {
left: auto;
min-width: 100%;
}

.nav > li li:hover > ul {
left: 100%;
top: -1px;
}

.nav > li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.nav li li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
border: 5px solid transparent;
right: 10px;
}
/* Prvy menu bar*/
.prve {
min-width: 100px;
border: 2px solid #81D4FA;
border-bottom: none;
border-top: none;
}
/* Druhy menu bar */
.druhe {
 min-width: 110px;
 border-right: 2px solid #81D4FA;
 }

.tretie {
right: 0;
}
```

Comment: [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/10rcrrwa/1/)?

Comment: No, it needs to be next to those menu bars on the same line as they are.

Comment: [how about this?](http://jsfiddle.net/10rcrrwa/2/)

Comment: close enough, but its making the whole menu bar bigger, I need it to be the same size as without this input box.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/10rcrrwa/6/  <-- this is the original size, i need it to be the same size but with the input text bar on the right size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/a2akavu7/1/). what i did was, made your `nav` display as block. and centered it with `margin:auto`. then added the text bar next to it. made it `float` and with `margin-top` i moved it up so it's in right place.

```
<body>
  <!--MENU BAR!-->
  <nav>
    <span class="nadpis"><a href="javascript:history.go(0)" style="text-transform: uppercase;"><?php echo $id_dom; ?></a></span>
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="prve">
        <a href="#">PSI</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="flvmena/meno1.html">Simoncik</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flvmena/meno2.html">Kodrla</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flvmena/meno3.html">Vajs</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flvmena/meno4.html">Hrebicek</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flcmena/meno1.html">Bednarikova</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flcmena/meno2.html">Dobrikova</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flcmena/meno3.html">Duracka</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="quamena/meno1.html">Klco</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="quamena/meno2.html">Cisar</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li><!--
   --><li class="druhe">
        <a href="#">&#9776;</a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="index.php">RPO</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flv.php?id_dom=flv">FLV</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="flvmena/meno1.html">Simoncik</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="flvmena/meno2.html">Kodrla</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="flvmena/meno3.html">Vajs</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="flvmena/meno4.html">Hrebicek</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flv.php?id_dom=FLC">FLC</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="flcmena/meno1.html">Bednarikova</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="flcmena/meno2.html">Dobrikova</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="flcmena/meno3.html">Duracka</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flv.php?id_dom=QUA">QUA</a>
            <ul>
              <li>
                <a href="quamena/meno1.html">Klco</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="quamena/meno2.html">Cisar</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flv.php?id_dom=HFX">HFX</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flv.php?id_dom=PDT">PDT</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flv.php?id_dom=RSH">RSH</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flv.php?id_dom=BUR">BUR</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="suhrn.php?id_dom=SUHRN" style="color: #ea9b54">SUHRN</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="suhrn.php?id_dom=INCI" style="color: #ea9b54">INCI</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="suhrn.php?id_dom=JIRA" style="color: #ea9b54">JIRA</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="suhrn.php?id_dom=CHGT" style="color: #ea9b54">CHGT</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="flv.php?id_dom=TASK" style="color: #ea9b54">TASK</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="vrs.php" style="color: #ea9b54">VRS</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <input type="text" class="tib" />
  </nav>


body,nav ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
/* menu*/
nav {
  display: inline-block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  /* text-align: center; */
  background-color: #303036;
  vertical-align: top;
  top: -1px;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: .3s;
}
nav ul > li > a{
  text-align:center;
}
ul.nav{
  margin:auto;
}
nav:hover {
  opacity: 1 !important;
  transition: .3s;
}
/*Nadpis - nazov domainu/reportu */
span.nadpis a{
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FAFAC1;
  background-color: #303036;
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue',sans-serif;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.nav a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #303036;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: .7em 1.7em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 85%;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  position: relative;
}

.nav {
  vertical-align: top;
  /* display: inline-block; */
  width: 250px;
}

.nav li {
  position: relative;
}

.nav > li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav li:hover > a {
  transition: .3s;
  background-color: #2e86ab;
  color: #8fc93a;
}

.nav ul {
  position: absolute;
  white-space: nowrap;
  z-index: 1;
  left: -99999em;
  border: 2px solid #81D4FA;
  border-top: 1px solid #81D4FA;
}

.nav > li:hover > ul {
  left: auto;
  min-width: 100%;
}

.nav > li li:hover > ul {
  left: 100%;
  top: -1px;
}

.nav > li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
}

.nav li li:hover > a:first-child:nth-last-child(2):before {
  border: 5px solid transparent;
  right: 10px;
}
/* Prvy menu bar*/
.prve {
  min-width: 100px;
  border: 2px solid #81D4FA;
  border-bottom: none;
  border-top: none;
}
/* Druhy menu bar */
.druhe {
  min-width: 110px;
  border-right: 2px solid #81D4FA;
}
.tib{
  float:right;
  margin-top:-28px;
}
```